# Named Pipes Error 40: Visual Studio 2012 MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, named-pipes

I have read through quite a few other sources and I am really confused. I am trying to connect to a MySQL server on my website. I am using a remote connection to access the MySQL server. I have whitelisted my IP address on the hosting server. In fact, I can open up the Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2012 and it will connect to the MySQL server just fine. It will run queries and display the results from the database.

I am utterly confused as to why it won't connect when I try to establish the connection in my code. After the server explorer makes the connection, it also gives you the connection string that it used to make the connection. I am using that string and it will not work.  Please help me understand why the server explorer can find the MySQL database, yet my code will not connect to it.

I am working in C#.

Here is my connection string from Visual Studio (the server explorer saved the password):

```
server=66.147.244.102;User Id=correct username;Persist Security Info=True;database=correct database name
```

Comment: That looks like a SQL Server connection string. Are you using `SqlConnection` to connect to your MySQL server...

Comment: Actually...yes I am.  That might be part of the problem.  I installed all of the MySQL stuff and extensions I thought in to my Visual Studio. what is the "using ....." that needs to go in to the top so I can hit the right libraries?

Comment: `SqlConnection` will connect you to Microsoft SQL Server. http://www.sqlines.com/_media/migration/embedded-sql-and-api/csharp/ado-net/cs-adonet-sql-server-mysql.png The picture suggests the namespace is `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I had to add the MySql reference in to my build and change up the code a bit to reflect...and done.  Connected.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is my connection string from Visual Studio (the server explorer saved the password):
>
> ```
> server=66.147.244.102;
> User Id=correct username;
> Persist Security Info=True;
> database=correct database name
> ```

That looks like a Microsoft SQL Server connection string, the one you'd use with `SqlConnection`. `SqlConnection` only knows how to connect to Microsoft SQL Server databases ... you'll need to use `MySqlConnection` to connect to your MySQL database.

[image]